# Doubt about two different approach to compute the fundamental group of closed orientable surface collapsed to a separating curve

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, group-presentation

Let $S$ be a closed orientabled surface of genus $2$ and $A$ a separaring curve as in the following figure:
[image]

I am trying to compute the fundamental group of $S/A$ by two different ways. Unfourtunately I am getting two different solutions

##### First solution.

It is clear that $S/A$ is homeomorphic to the wedge sum of two torus $T=S^1\times S^1$. By the Example 1.21 of Hatcher's book we can conclude that:
$$\pi_1(T\vee T)\cong \pi_1(T)\star \pi_1(T)$$
Denote by $a,b$ the 1-cells of the first torus and $c,d$ the 1-cells of the second one. Then:
$$\pi_1(T\vee T)\cong\langle a,b\, |\, [a,b]\rangle \star \langle c,d\,|\, [c,d]\rangle=\langle a,b,c,d\, |\, [a,b], [c,d]\rangle.$$

##### Second solution.

Denote by $C(A)$ the cone:
$$C(A)=\frac{A\times [0,1]}{(x,1)\sim(x',1), \forall x,x'\in A},$$
and attach it to $S$ via the inclusion map $i:A\subset S\to C(A)$ given by:
$$i(x)=q(x,0),$$
being $q$ the quotient map $A\times [0,1]\to C(A)$. It can be show that the resulting space $S\cup_iC(A)$ has the same homotopy type than $S/A$. The map $i$ is clearly homotopic equivalent to the constant map $x\mapsto q(x,1)\in C(A)$.

By the Proposition 0.18 of the Hatcher's book:

> **Proposition 0.18.** *If $(X_1,A)$ is a $CW$-pair and we have attaching maps $f,g:A\to X_0$ that are homotopic, then $X_0\cup_f X_1\simeq X_0\cup_g X_1$ rel $X_0$.*

we can conclude that $S\cup_iC(A)$ and $S\vee C(A)$ has isomorphic fundamental groups. Then:
$$\pi_1(S/A)\cong \pi_1(S)\star \pi_1(C(A)).$$
Now, each loop in $C(A)$ is homotopic to a constant loop and in consequence has trivial funamental group. If we denote by $a,b,c,d$ the $1$-cells of the standard CW structure of $S$, then:
$$\pi_1(S/A)\cong \pi_1(S)\cong \langle a,b,c,d\, |\, [a,b][c,d]\rangle.$$

##### The problem.

From by (very limited) knowledge of group presentation, the first solution:
$$\langle a,b,c,d\, |\, [a,b], [c,d]\rangle$$
cannot be isomorphic to the second one:
$$\langle a,b,c,d\, |\, [a,b][c,d]\rangle$$

What's wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: I suspect your notation $i:A\subset S\to C(A)$ has gone awry, I cannot make much sense of it.

Comment: Your account of Proposition 0.18 looks very suspicious. I suggest that you edit your post to include the statement of that proposition exactly as it is in Hatcher's book, so that we can try to debug your proof without having to go searching for our copy of Hatcher.

Comment: @LeeMosher I have editted by question. Fortunately, the David's answer is useful enough for me. Many thanks for your time.

Comment: Thanks. A good title, and more information in the post, makes the question useful for others as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first solution is correct, and you are also correct that the two group presentations you have written down define non-isomorphic groups. You error lies in your second solution. In particular it is hiding in the line

> By the Proposition 0.18 of the Hatcher's book, we can conclude that $S\cup_i C(A)$ and $S\vee C(A)$ has isomorphic fundamental groups.

What Hatcher says is that if the maps $i,i'\colon A\subset S\to C(A)$ are homotopic then $S\cup_i C(A)$ and $S\cup_{i'} C(A)$ are homotopic relative to $C(A)$. Here $i'$ is the map which sends $A$ to the cone point of $C(A)$.

The mistake you have made is in saying that $S\cup_{i'} C(A)=S\vee C(A)$, it does not. When $i'$ collapses $A$ to the cone point of $C(A)$, it collapses $A$ in $S$ too, so in fact $S\cup_{i'} C(A)=S/A\vee C(A)$ which deformation retracts onto $S/A$, and there is no contradiction.

Here are some illustrative pictures:

[image]

Comment: Very nice explanation. Now I can see by mistake crearly! Thanks for your time